# next.js iframe "github refused to connect"

Tags: reactjs, next.js, iframe

I would like to add a github repo on a website in a "iframe". Got error "github refused to connect". Others webs works fine.

I added also react-iframe.

```
import Iframe from "react-iframe";
import Head from "next/head";

const Telemetry: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        <title>Telemetry</title>
      </Head>
      <Iframe url="https://github.com/xxxx" width="640px" height="320px" id="" className="" display="block" position="relative" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Telemetry;
```

Was searching the web for the answers - with no success.

console : Refused to frame 'https://github.com/' because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors 'none'".